# What is the function that PHPMyADmin uses when an individual uses the "export as PDF/CSV"?

Tags: php, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a simple question regarding PHPMyAdmin, and that is, I want to know the SQL command that PHPMyAdmin uses when I use "export as PDF/CSV".

Normally, PHPMyAdmin would let you know the functions it (presented often on the top of the page) used when you apply a command/function, however, when you use the "Export" tab, this window is obfuscated by your output.

My question is simply - what is the "Export as PDF/CSV" function that PHPMyAdmin uses?

Thank you.

Comment: Export as PDF uses the tcPDF library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not only one function...
its calling a new excel workbook and dynamically filling it with data.
that can be achieved in many ways, but the most popular might be the PHPExcel extension
[PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com)

Comment: Cool. Thanks Vogel612 and Mark Baker.